# Numerical integration's speed

Tags: numerical-integration, matlab

Consider this numerical integration of Bessel function:

```
Do[NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 10000}], {i, 1, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.033403, Null}

This is the similar code in Matlab:

```
clc
clear all;
f = @(x) besselj(2,x);

tic
for i=1:100
integral(f,0,10000);
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.860757 seconds.
>
> ans: 0.9964

How can I make the numerical integration in Mathematica as fast as Matlab?
I want to do some minimization which involves the numerical integration of a complicated function of Bessel functions and its zeros. Mathematica calculates the zeros and the integrate slower than Matlab. I think this considerably will affect the computation speed because if Matlab is fast about 1 second then the many times of evaluation of these Bessel zeros and integrals accumulate a lot of time.

Could it be that the speed difference is due to being `for` faster in Matlab than `Do` in Mathematica?

But if someone calculates just one integral and use BesselJ[200,x] then there is a difference, or if Someone uses:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[200, x] + Sin[x], {x, 0, 30000}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.340000, 2.593083412014634}

```
clc
clear all;
f = @(x)  besselj(200,x)+sin(x);
tic
integral(f,0,30000)
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.264900 seconds.
>
> ans :2.5931

I use Mathematica 9 and Matlab 2014a on Windows7.

Comment: If one omits the "Do", via `NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, #}] & /@ ConstantArray[10000, 100]` it is not really faster, so I do not think it is the "Do"-Loop what makes it slow.

Comment: do they get the same result?

Comment: @george2079 Yes, they do.

Comment: I wonder what's the output of matlab? Is it still reliable?

Comment: @xzczd it's 0.9964

Comment: I have a comment about your example of `BesselJ[200, x] + Sin[x]`. In the case where there are multi-frequency oscillations, it's easier to integrate them one by one and sum over the result. You can find `NIntegrate[#, {x, 0, 30000}] & /@ (BesselJ[200, x] +  Sin[x]) // AbsoluteTiming` takes significantly shorter time. In general, you can first `Collect` different frequencies, and then `NIntegrate` them one by one.

Comment: This speed might be influenced by `Method` option settings.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau When I calculate the integral for a very long list in Matlab, it uses all of the CPU cores available. This is not true when I use Mathematica. You can take a look at these two questions which I think gave the same problem:

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77589/nintegrate-over-a-list-of-functions

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/ndsolve-in-mathematica-wont-use-all-the-cores-avaiable

Answer (score 4):

```
Parallelize[
  Do[NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 10000}], {i, 1, 100}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

on same PC

```
clc
clear all;
f = @(x) besselj(2,x);

tic
for i=1:100
integral(f,0,10000);
end
toc

 %Elapsed time is 0.924171 seconds.
```

Just to note, tic/toc and `AbsoluteTiming` measure elapsed time, not cpu time. On mutlicore, it is possible that elapsed time is smaller than CPU time.  Using CPU time, the result is

```
Timing[Do[NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, x], {x, 0, 10000}], {i, 1, 100}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While Matlab 2015a

```
clc
clear all;
f = @(x) besselj(2,x);

t=cputime; 
for i=1:100
integral(f,0,10000);
end
cputime-t

%ans =
   %5.5848
```

So Mathematica actually used less total CPU time than Matlab. But its elapsed time was larger. It looks like Matlab used more cores (I have 8 cores). So by forcing `Parallelize`, Mathematica now used cores more efficiently than otherwise. That what it appears what happened, but I am not an expert on this so I could be wrong.

Comment: so are you saying that `matlab` parallelisms for you?

Comment: What if you would use parallelization for Matlab too? I think both cases must be either parallel or not parallel.
The other thing is that if someone calculates just one integral and use `BesselJ[200,x]` then there is a lot of difference.

Comment: On my system if I use parallelization for Matlab, then it is faster.

Comment: @Nasser Could you use parallelization for Matlab too? I think the answer is not that Matlab uses more cores. If you use parallelization for Matlab and get the same performance as Mathematica then you're right.

Comment: @yashar Have you checked your task manager? If matlab doesn't use multi-core then the CPU utilization rate should be quite low.