# ODE solving and NDSolveValue error depending on parameters

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

Given the two sets of $2N$ equations

```
Eu[n_, i_] := ((I*k)/(2*Pi))*Subscript[λu, i][t] - Sum[If[j != i, Coth[(Subscript[λu, j][t] - Subscript[λu, i][t])/2], 0], {j, 1, n}] + (1/2)*Sum[Tanh[(Subscript[λt, j][t] - Subscript[λu, i][t] - mt)/2] + Tanh[(Subscript[λt, j][t] -Subscript[λu, i][t] + mu)/2], {j, 1, n}]; 
Et[n_, i_] := (-((I*k)/(2*Pi)))*Subscript[λt, i][t] - Sum[If[j != i, Coth[(Subscript[λt, j][t] - Subscript[λt, i][t])/2], 0], {j, 1, n}] + (1/2)*Sum[Tanh[(Subscript[λu, j][t] - Subscript[λt, i][t] - mu)/2] + Tanh[(Subscript[λu, j][t] - Subscript[λt, i][t] + mt)/2], {j, 1, n}];
```

I need to solve the following system of ODE

```
Eqs[n_] := Flatten[Table[{τu*D[Subscript[λu, i][t], t] == Eu[n, i], τt*D[Subscript[λt, i][t], t] == Et[n, i]}, {i, n}]];
```

with the following initial values

```
ICs[n_] := Flatten[Table[{Subscript[λu, i][0] == 0.1*i, Subscript[λt, i][0] == 0.1*i}, {i, n}]];
```

The functions to determine are the following

```
Vars[n_] := Join[Table[Subscript[λu, i], {i, n}], Table[Subscript[λt, i], {i, n}]];
```

In particular I need to determine numerically late solution (i.e. solution for $t$ enough big such that the `Eu` and `Et` value is small) of the initial value problem for some large value of $N$ (the larger the better), say at least $N \gtrsim 200$ for certain value of the other parameters $k$, $\tau_u$, $\tau_t$, $m_u$ and $m_t$. So I used

```
n = 200; 
k = 1; 
τu = 1; 
τt = 1; 
mu = 2.; 
mt = -2.5; 
sol = NDSolveValue[Join[Eqs[n], ICs[n]], Vars[n], {t, 0, 1000}];
```

What I get is the following message

```
NDSolveValue::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.
```

However if I add the option as it suggest I get

```
NDSolveValue::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.

NDSolveValue::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.
```

Notice that all works from the beginning if i let `n=100` or so. The problem is that I need the result for larger values of $N$.

Can you suggest me something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is already discussed in

[What's behind Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136114/1871)

so I'd like not to talk too much about it in this answer. In short, `NDSolve` is having difficulty in recognizing the system is an ODE system and the DAE solver of `NDSolve` isn't strong enough (at least now) so we need to help `NDSolve` to choose an ODE solver. One possible solution is to use [`` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/1871):

```
rhs[n_] := Flatten@Transpose@Table[{Eu[n, i]/τu, Et[n, i]/τt}, {i, n}];
vars[n_] := Table[{Subscript[λu, i], Subscript[λt, i]}, {i, n}] // Transpose // Flatten;
icvalues[n_] := Table[{0.1 i, 0.1 i}, {i, n}] // Transpose;
rhsnumeric = 
   Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[vars[n][t] // Through, 
     rhs@n, {2 n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {13.9278, Null} *)

sol = 
   NDSolveValue[{v'[t] == rhsnumeric@v@t, v[0] == Flatten@icvalues@n}, 
    v, {t, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {138.54, Null} *)
```

The calculation inside `NDSolve` is slow so I choose `1` as end of time for illustration. If you have a C compiler installed then we can speed up the code a bit with a more advanced solution:

```
rhscompiled = 
  Hold@Compile[{{utlst, _Complex, 2}}, 
       Transpose@Table[{Eu[n, i]/τu, Et[n, i]/τt}, {i, n}], 
       RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False, CompilationTarget -> C] //. 
     Flatten@{DownValues /@ {Eu, Et}, 
              OwnValues /@ Unevaluated@{n, k, τu, τt, mu, mt}} /. 
    {Subscript[λu, i_][t] -> Compile`GetElement[utlst, 1, i], 
     Subscript[λt, i_][t] -> Compile`GetElement[utlst, 2, i]} // ReleaseHold;

solcompiled = NDSolveValue[{v'[t] == rhscompiled@v@t, v[0] == icvalues@n}, 
    v, {t, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {45.4734, Null} *)

Plot[solcompiled[t] // Abs, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Notice the structure of output of `sol` and `solcompiled` is a bit different.

Comment: It seems great! However I noticed that during the solution just one process is active. It is possible to parallelize it?

Comment: @MaPo It's hard (if not impossible). Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78278/1871 (Well, I do notice that in recent versions `NDSolve` parallelizes automatically when solving certain ODE system, but it's not (yet) clear when it can. )

Comment: @MaPo As to parallelization, I've started a new question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208784/1871