# How to speed up NDSolve when there are ~400k equations?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm trying to use `NDSolve` to solve a set of ~400k equations. The problem I met is: when I ran the evaluation, Mathematica (version 11.0) raised an error:

```
NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.
```

However, after I added the option `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}` into the evaluation, **it took almost 24h to get the anwsers**.

So, **what does the option `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}` really means? Are there other ways I can get the equations solved correctly and quickly, maybe in 1h?**

Below are my simlified codes:

```
(*Equations*)
EqD[nC_,nN_] := c[nC,nN]'[t];
Eqk[nC_,nN_] := Sum[b[nC-i,nN-(1-i),i,1-i]*c[nC-i,nN-(1-i)][t]-(b[nC,nN,i,1-i]+a[nC,nN,i,1-i])*c[nC,nN][t]+a[nC+i,nN+(1-i),i,1-i]*c[nC+i,nN+(1-i)][t],{i,{0,1}}];
Eq[nC_,nN_] := EqD[nC,nN] == Eqk[nC,nN];
(*Coefficients*)
b[nC_,nN_,i_,j_] := 4\[Pi]*(R[nC,nN]+R[i,j])/\[CapitalOmega]*D\[Alpha][i,j]*c[i,j][t];
a[nC_,nN_,i_,j_] := 4\[Pi]*(R[nC-i,nN-j]+R[i,j])/\[CapitalOmega]*D\[Alpha][i,j]*Exp[-((F[nC-i,nN-j]+F[i,j]-F[nC,nN])/(k*T))]
(*Other definitions needed*)
R[nC_,nN_] := (3(nC+nN)*\[CapitalOmega]/(4\[Pi]))^(1/3)
D\[Alpha][i_,j_] := 0;D\[Alpha][1,0] := 8.0*10^-4;D\[Alpha][0,1] := 1.0*10^-4;
F[nC_,nN_] := -k*T*Log[(nC+nN)!/(nC!*nN!)]+(nC*Fc[nC+nN]+nN*Fn[nC+nN])/(nC+nN);
(*\[Pi],\[CapitalOmega],k and T are constants;Fc[nC_] and Fn[nN_] are two functions related to R[nC,0] and R[0,nN]*)
```

Are there any useful suggestions to speed up my evaluation?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @LammondW The code contains many typos. I recommend formulating the problem in the form of equations.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sorry to mislead you, and I will re-edit the description to make it clear right now.

Comment: You code involves things like `Cinit = 0.439673 %` inside a `Module`, which is obviously incorrect. Please notice `%` doesn't represent percentage in _Mathematica_, it's the short form of `Out`.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for your reminding me. I've simplified the code to make it easy to understand for those who aren't familiar with material computing, so there may be some mistakes.  Anyway, I've corrected the error. Thanks again!

Comment: How much time does `{Sys,Bc} = PrepareEquations[tMin,tMax,NoC,NoN];` take? "So, what does the option `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}` really means?" We already have this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871

Comment: @xzczd `{Sys,Bc} = PrepareEquations[tMin,tMax,NoC,NoN];` takes 8 mins to prepare the ~320k equations. Besides, I've read the post before but it didn't make sense to me then. I'll give it a careful look and thinking again. Thanks!

Comment: Don't miss those posts linked to that post, for example this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208770/1871

Comment: I've had similar problems with large systems before.  One thing you might try to identify the problem is breaking up the `NDSolve` into stages as described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html).  I even went so far as trying to rewrite `NDSolve``ProcessEquations` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202980/can-we-construct-our-own-ndsolvestatedata); sometimes this helped, but never enough.  When I'm really stuck, I end up resorting to VODE/FORTRAN, which is very fast but ugly.

Comment: It's possible you ran up against a time constraint to `Solve` for the derivatives.  It can be set with `"NDSolveOptions" -> "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> time`. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131428/4999 for details.

Comment: Why do you remove the code sample? Indeed, it's not a good sample (not sufficiently simplified), but a question with no code sample is worse.

Comment: @xzczd Sorry! I'm trying to simplify the code as not to involve my research purposes. You know. My supervisor disliked it. I'll make it as soon as possible.

Comment: Well, then do you know you code is still visible in the [revision history](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/211644/revisions)?

Comment: @xzczd Haha actually I didn't know that (the reason I needed to delete it is that my supervisor didn't want the codes to be public). I've post a new version of codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested the code as it is without optimization. I give a report and general recommendations:
Test 1

```
In[11]:= Equations[tMin, tMax, 200, 20]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[11]= {7.76804, Null}
```

Test 2

```
In[12]:= Equations[tMin, tMax, 200, 200]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[12]= {86.8025, Null}
```

Test 3

```
In[13]:= Equations[tMin, tMax, 2000, 20]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[13]= {109.039, Null}
```

Test 4

```
In[14]:= Equations[tMin, tMax, 2000, 200]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[14]= {2174.46, Null}
```

And so it took 36 minutes, 30-50% of the CPU and 12GB of memory (maximum). Most of the time 1 kernel worked. I think that we can reduce the time to 3-5 minutes. Version report:

```
 $Version

Out[]= "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"
```

Let's start the optimization. Here we are dealing with the Riccati matrix equation 
$$c'=c.A.c+B1.c+c.B2...(1) $$
where `c` is a 2000x200 matrix. Therefore we used `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"`to solve it. Then it takes about 36 min on my ASUS laptop. We can reduce time by simple replacement `t->tmax t`. The corresponding code is

```
PrepareEquations[tMin_, tMax_, NoC_, NoN_] := 
  Module[{i, 
    j,(*C and N species*)\[Alpha]C = 1,(*C monomer*)\[Alpha]N = 
     1,(*N monomer*)nCmin = 0, nCmax = NoC,(*Number of C atoms*)
    nNmin = 0, nNmax = NoN,(*Number of N atoms*)
    c0 = 10^-30(*For numerical stability,avoid null value*)}, 
   Print["Function: PrepareEquations"];
   Clear[c, a, b, F, Fc, Fn];
   Cinit = 0.00439673;(*Initial C concentration*)
   Ninit = 0.00761477;(*Initial N concentration*)
   k = 1.380649*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant,unit J/K*)
   T = 723;(*Temperature,unit K*)
   R[nC_, nN_] := ((3*(nC + nN)*0.0118)/(4 \[Pi]))^(1/3);(*Radius*)
   D\[Alpha][i_, j_] := 0;(*Diffusion coefficients*)
   D\[Alpha][\[Alpha]C, 0] := 8.0*10^-4;
   D\[Alpha][0, \[Alpha]N] := 1.0*10^-4;
   k\[Alpha][nC_, nN_, i_, j_] := 
    4 \[Pi]*(R[nC, nN] + R[i, j])/0.0118*D\[Alpha][i, j];
   (*Calculation of energy*)RsC = 0.02780299;
   \[Sigma]C = 4.09324*10^-19;
   Fc[nC_] := 4 \[Pi]*(R[nC, 0])^2*\[Sigma]C*(1 - RsC/R[nC, 0]);
   \[Sigma]N = 5.54492*10^-20;
   RsN = -0.14758424;
   Fn[nN_] := 4 \[Pi]*(R[0, nN])^2*\[Sigma]N*(1 - RsN/R[0, nN]);
   F[nC_, 
     nN_] := -k*T*
      Log[(nC + nN)!/(nC!*nN!)] + (nC*Fc[nC + nN] + 
        nN*Fn[nC + nN])/(nC + nN);
   b[nC_, nN_, i_, j_] := 
    k\[Alpha][nC, nN, i, j]*c[i, j][t];(*Condensation rate*)
   a[nC_, nN_, i_, j_] := 
    k\[Alpha][nC - i, nN - j, i, j]*
     Exp[-((F[nC - i, nN - j] + F[i, j] - F[nC, nN])/(k*
           T))];(*Emission rate*)a[i_, j_, i_, j_] := 0;(*Monomer*)
   a[0, nN_, 1, j_] := 0;
   a[nC_, 0, i_, 1] := 0;
   Clear[CL, Eqk, EqD, Eq];
   With[{},(*Initial conditions*)CL[nC_, nN_] := c[nC, nN][tMin] == 0;
    (*Definition of the equilibrium equations*)
    EqD[nC_, nN_] := c[nC, nN]'[t];
    Eqk[nC_, nN_] := 
     Sum[b[nC - i, nN - (1 - i), i, 1 - i]*
        c[nC - i, nN - (1 - i)][
         t] - (b[nC, nN, i, 1 - i] + a[nC, nN, i, 1 - i])*
        c[nC, nN][t] + 
       a[nC + i, nN + (1 - i), i, 1 - i]*
        c[nC + i, nN + (1 - i)][t], {i, {0, 1}}];
    Eq[nC_, nN_] := EqD[nC, nN] == tMax Eqk[nC, nN];
    (*Definition of equilibrium concentrations for each special size*)
    Module[{nC, nN}, nC = nCmax;
     For[nN = 1, nN < nNmax, nN++, 
      Eqk[nC, nN] = (b[nC, nN - 1, 0, 1]*
           c[nC, nN - 1][t] - (b[nC, nN, 0, 1] + a[nC, nN, 0, 1])*
           c[nC, nN][t] + 
          a[nC, nN + 1, 0, 1]*
           c[nC, nN + 1][t]) + (b[nC - 1, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC - 1, nN][t] -
           a[nC, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC, nN][t])];
     nN = nNmax;
     For[nC = 1, nC < nCmax, nC++, 
      Eqk[nC, nN] = (b[nC - 1, nN, 1, 0]*
           c[nC - 1, nN][t] - (b[nC, nN, 1, 0] + a[nC, nN, 1, 0])*
           c[nC, nN][t] + 
          a[nC + 1, nN, 1, 0]*
           c[nC + 1, nN][t]) + (b[nC, nN - 1, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN - 1][t] -
           a[nC, nN, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN][t])];
     nC = 0;
     For[nN = 2, nN < nNmax, nN++, 
      Eqk[nC, nN] = (b[nC, nN - 1, 0, 1]*
           c[nC, nN - 1][t] - (b[nC, nN, 0, 1] + a[nC, nN, 0, 1])*
           c[nC, nN][t] + 
          a[nC, nN + 1, 0, 1]*
           c[nC, nN + 1][t]) + (-b[nC, nN, 1, 0] c[nC, nN][t] + 
          a[nC + 1, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC + 1, nN][t])];
     nN = 0;
     For[nC = 2, nC < nCmax, nC++, 
      Eqk[nC, nN] = (b[nC - 1, nN, 1, 0]*
           c[nC - 1, nN][t] - (b[nC, nN, 1, 0] + a[nC, nN, 1, 0])*
           c[nC, nN][t] + 
          a[nC + 1, nN, 1, 0]*
           c[nC + 1, nN][t]) + (-b[nC, nN, 0, 1] c[nC, nN][t] + 
          a[nC, nN + 1, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN + 1][t])];
     nC = nCmax; nN = 0;
     Eqk[nC, 
       nN] = (-b[nC, nN, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN][t] + 
         a[nC, nN + 1, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN + 1][t]) + (b[nC - 1, nN, 1, 0]*
          c[nC - 1, nN][t] - a[nC, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC, nN][t]);
     nC = 0; nN = nNmax;
     Eqk[nC, 
       nN] = (-b[nC, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC, nN][t] + 
         a[nC + 1, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC + 1, nN][t]) + (b[nC, nN - 1, 0, 1]*
          c[nC, nN - 1][t] - a[nC, nN, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN][t]);
     nC = nCmax; nN = nNmax;
     Eqk[nC, 
       nN] = (b[nC, nN - 1, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN - 1][t] - 
         a[nC, nN, 0, 1]*c[nC, nN][t]) + (b[nC - 1, nN, 1, 0]*
          c[nC - 1, nN][t] - a[nC, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC, nN][t]);
     nC = 0; nN = 0;
     CL[nC, nN] = c[nC, nN][tMin] == 0;
     Eqk[nC, nN] = 0;
     nC = \[Alpha]C; nN = 0;
     CL[nC, nN] = c[nC, nN][tMin] == Cinit + c0;
     Eqk[nC, 
       nN] = (-b[nC, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC, nN][t] + 
         a[nC + 1, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC + 1, nN][t]) + (-b[nC, nN, 0, 1]*
          c[nC, nN][t] + 
         a[nC, nN + 1, 0, 1]*
          c[nC, nN + 1][
           t]) - (Sum[(b[x, y, nC, nN] - a[x, y, nC, nN])*
           c[x, y][t], {x, 0, nCmax - 1}, {y, 0, nNmax}] + 
         Sum[(-a[nCmax, i, nC, nN]*c[nCmax, i][t]), {i, 0, nNmax}]);
     nC = 0; nN = \[Alpha]N;
     CL[nC, nN] = c[nC, nN][tMin] == Ninit + c0;
     Eqk[nC, 
       nN] = (-b[nC, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC, nN][t] + 
         a[nC + 1, nN, 1, 0]*c[nC + 1, nN][t]) + (-b[nC, nN, 0, 1]*
          c[nC, nN][t] + 
         a[nC, nN + 1, 0, 1]*
          c[nC, nN + 1][
           t]) - (Sum[(b[x, y, nC, nN] - a[x, y, nC, nN])*
           c[x, y][t], {x, 0, nCmax}, {y, 0, nNmax - 1}] + 
         Sum[(-a[i, nNmax, nC, nN]*c[i, nNmax][t]), {i, 0, nCmax}]);];
    Bc := 
     Flatten[ParallelTable[
        c[nC, nN], {nC, 0, nCmax}, {nN, 0, nNmax}]] // Evaluate];
   DistributeDefinitions[Eq, CL];
   Sys = Join[
       Flatten[ParallelTable[
         Eq[nC, nN], {nC, 0, nCmax}, {nN, 0, nNmax}]], 
       Flatten[ParallelTable[
         CL[nC, nN], {nC, 0, nCmax}, {nN, 0, nNmax}]]] // Flatten // 
     Evaluate;
   {Sys, Bc}];
tMin = 0; tMax = 7.75*10^5;
```

Here we have replaced only one equation `Eq[nC_, nN_] := EqD[nC, nN] == tMax Eqk[nC, nN];`.Now we call

```
PrepareEquations[tMin, tMax, 2000, 200]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

And it takes `{536.24, Null}`. Now we solve the system on `{t, 0, 1}`:

```
RSol = NDSolve[Sys, Bc, {t, tMin, 1}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> 
       "Residual"}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes only `{1148.03, Null}`. Thus, we saved 9 minutes with a simple replacement `t->tmax t`. However, if we can write the equation in matrix form, then we can use  exponential Rosenbrock-type integrators. Then we can reduce the time to 1 minute.

Comment: Additionally, I use all the 24 cores hardly. Does it matter? Of course I'll check it too. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @LammondW Version 12 is much faster on ODE systems than version 11. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208590/numerically-solving-a-system-of-many-coupled-non-linear-odes-efficiently

Comment: Thanks for your patience and kindness and detailed anwser. I'll figure it out and then reply to you^_^

Comment: Thanks for your anwser again!! Someone else also suggested I should use a vector form of equations. Honestly I'm not very well with Mathematica, so I'm wondering whether the method applies to the situation where I will change the number of equations (namely `nC` and `nN`)?

Comment: I've checked your optimization and here's another problem. The solution gained using your method is a series of `InterpolatingFunction` with a domain of {0.,1.}, while I need them in the domain of {0.,tMax}. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: Then use it in a form `c[nC,nN][t1/tMax]`, with `{t1, 0, tMax}`.

Comment: Brilliantly! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LammondW You're welcome!