# When does NDSolve parallelize ODE system solving?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parallelization

I've [long believed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78578/1871) that `NDSolve` cannot make use of multiple cores to solve ODE system, but things seem to be different at least since *v12*. Consider the following toy example:

```
$Version
(* "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 19, 2019)" *)
(* Tested on a 8-core machine. *)

eq = 2 y''[x] == y'[x] - 3 y[x] - 4;
ic = {y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 7};

With[{n = 4096}, sys = Table[{eq, ic} /. y -> y@i, {i, n}];
                 NDSolve[sys, y /@ Range@n, {x, 0, 10^3}]]
```

[image]

Seems that when `n >= 4096`, `NDSolve` automatically parallelizes. I'm pretty sure this isn't the case in *v9*.

So my question is:

1. In which version was this optimization introduced?
2. In what situation does the parallelization happen? More tests show the threshold depends on the specific system being solved. In certain situations (e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208770/1871)) parallelization seems to never happen.
3. Can we make `NDSolve` parallel for `n < 4096`? Is the parallelization controlled by any option?

Comment: I have seen `NDSolve` parallelization on several occasions, and not just with enormous numbers of equations.  However, I did not pay attention to the characteristics of the equations to be solved.  Good question (+1).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The number `8192` is an autoparallelization threshold (see `SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]`). There are `2*4096 = 8192` variables, `y[k]` and `y'[k]`, in the system, perhaps a coincidence. The threshold can be lowered with `SetSystemOptions`, and one can see that when it is run, autoparallelization kicks in.

```
With[{ops = SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions[
   "ParallelOptions" -> 
    "VectorParallelLengthThresholds" -> {8192, 8192, 8192, 8192, 
       8192}/2
   ],
  With[{n = 4096/2}, sys = Table[{eq, ic} /. y -> y@i, {i, n}];
   NDSolve[sys, y /@ Range@n, {x, 0, 10^3}]],
  SetSystemOptions[ops]
  ]]
```

This is a system arithmetic feature (vectorization), not an `NDSolve` feature per se.

Comment: +1, perhaps 'autocompilation' is not quite the right term

Comment: @ilian Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Just a side note: in _v11.3_ there's no `VectorParallelLengthThresholds` option. There's a `"MachineFunctionParallelThresholds"` option whose option value is `{196608, 98304, 98304, 65536, 49152}`, but lowering the option value doesn't seem to trigger parallelization.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for the bounty.  Your comment explains why I couldn't find [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39169902#39169902). Comparing the `ParallelOptions"` suggests internal parallelization has changed in V12. In V11.3 with `n = 4096`, I get up to 200% kernel activity (which I interpret as 2 of 4 cores being used), but I cannot find a way to control a threshold for it (neither `"VectorArithmeticThresholds"` nor `"MachineFunctionParallelThresholds"` made a difference).