Automatic parallelization of vector ODEs?
I read that if an ODE
dX/dt=F[t,X}
where X and F are vectors, is written in a vector form, the computation will be parallelized automatically. Thus I did no explicit parallelization in my Mathematica programs solving such equations. However, it seems that the computations are slow (although I haven't done measurements on computers with different numbers of processor cores).
Now I am going to rewrite these programs using explicit parallelization which is easy because the numerical algorithms are explicitly parallel (unlike, say, Monte Carlo). Will it be a useless effort?
Additional information. I don't use Mathematica's NDSolve, I use Runge-Kutta 4 and 5 programmed myself. My core functions are compiled in C, and I use Microsoft Visual Studio C compiler on Windows and GCC compiler on Linux and Mac.
It seems that modern processors and good compilers (?) do automatic parallelization even if the ODE is not written in a vector form. Compiler usually tries to parallelize the innermost loop and, if there are no dependencies, distributes the load over different processor cores.
What specialists could say about it? Thank you in advance for your consideration!
Here is a toy example
(* Initialization*)
SetSystemOptions[
  "ParallelOptions" -> {"ParallelThreadNumber" -> Automatic, 
    "MKLThreadNumber" -> Automatic}];

Size = 10000; NIter = 100;
Matr = ParallelTable[1./Size, {i, 1, Size}, {j, 1, Size}];
Vec = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Size}];
X0 = Table[0., {i, 1, Size}];

(* Execution*)
X = X0;
Do[X = Vec + Matr . X, {i, 1, NIter}] // AbsoluteTiming


Results for the execution time on my 8-core Windows laptop:
*) "ParallelThreadNumber" -> Automatic, "MKLThreadNumber" -> Automatic:
53.5355
*) "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1, "MKLThreadNumber" -> 1:
53.6108
*) "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 8, "MKLThreadNumber" -> 1:
55.9189
Now the similar but compiled
(* Initialization*)
SetSystemOptions[
  "ParallelOptions" -> {"ParallelThreadNumber" -> Automatic, 
    "MKLThreadNumber" -> Automatic}];

Size = 10000; NIter = 1000;
Matr = ParallelTable[1./Size, {i, 1, Size}, {j, 1, Size}];
Vec = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, Size}];
X0 = Table[0., {i, 1, Size}];

SolveODE = 
 Compile[{{X0, _Real, 1}, {Vec, _Real, 1}, {Matr, _Real, 
    2}, {NIter, _Integer}},
  Module[{X},
   X = X0;
   Do[X = Vec + Matr . X, {i, 1, NIter}];
   Mean[X]
   ]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]

(*Execution*)
SolveODE[X0, Vec, Matr, NIter] // AbsoluteTiming

Here Mathematica tries to parallelize for all parallel settings except of
"ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1, "MKLThreadNumber" -> 1

but fails as the processor load becomes high but the execution takes the same 30 seconds on my computer.
The result of this experiment shows that probably Mathematica does not have an ability to automatically parallelize the code, unlike some compilers. Thus one has to use the "Parallel..." commands and the trick of defining compiled functions with dimensions of the arguments by one smaller than the actual dimension. And the best choice for the parallelization parameters is 1,1, as above.
Dmitry

Can you be more specific? Have you read the following posts?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208784/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/1871 And please notice that, unless you have certain special reason(s), you should not code your own ODE solver instead of NDSolve.

I am solving huge ODEs of dimensions 10^4 to 10^5 for many-body problems such as systems of classical particles and classical spins. With such a size, I don't believe there is a need to use the automatic step, so I discretize the ODEs with the constant time step Delta t. I know one can customize NDSolve to use any method with or without an automatic time step but I prefer transparency and use Runge-Kutta which is easy to program as it looks like a formula for one variable although I apply it to vectors. It works well enough, although I have a concern about automatic parallelization.

I read the two recommended posts. The first one is interesting because there are recommendations for how to control parallelization using NDSolve. The second one is a primer on Parallelization. I know this stuff and I use ParallelDo with success when I need to solve the same ODE for different values of parameters such as the temperature T.

SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"] may give you information about when packed-array arithmetic is vectorized in internal libraries (takes advantage of Intel and Apple ARM cpu instruction sets). This automatic parallelization is much more efficient than using Mathematica's Parallel* functions. You need to make sure your arrays stay packed. You don't mention this, so I mention it in case you didn't know it was an issue. Also, I'm wondering why not just do the work in C instead of Mathematica? Or port your C code to an Mma LibraryFunction?

I searched SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"] in the Mathematica documentation and haven't found anything. My vectors are created with the Table command and then they undergo standard mathematical operations, so I see no reason for them to become unpacked. I used Fortran and I am using Mathematica as Fortran. I write formulas and Mathematica computes them. I don't understand C, it is non-intuitive for me.

You need to add e.g. @MichaelE2 in your comment otherwise MIchael E2 won't get the reminder. (See this post for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284701 ) As to SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"], yes, it's not well-documented AFAIK, but you can find some discussion in this site.

@ xzczd. In fact, I have at the beginning of my programs
SetSystemOptions[
"ParallelOptions" -> {"ParallelThreadNumber" -> 1,
"MKLThreadNumber" -> 1}];
These options are not documented. Now I tried to change them in the program that is not explicitly parallelized and does not contain Parallel commands, although it contains loops that could be parallelized by a smart compiler - there is no effect. It seems Mathematica does not have an ability to automatically parallelize and I have to do it explicitly. Correct me if I am wrong...
